# Delphi - Making a program to work on some text and pasting it in parts in another window

Tags: delphi

I am trying to make a program that would work on some text (remove all the ".", put together 2 blocks of text and pasting the result in another program, going trhu text fields using TAB.

Here is where I am now in the code:

```
unit Banri;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Clipbrd, sndkey32;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    EditTexto: TEdit;
    ButtonGO: TButton;
    procedure ButtonGOClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  SL: TStringList;
  Count: Integer;
  Appwin : hWnd;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

  var
  TextoCompleto: String;


procedure TForm1.ButtonGOClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TextoCompleto:= Trim(EditTexto.Text);
  Appwin:= FindWindow(PChar(0),'Banrisul');
  if Appwin <> 0 then
  begin
      StringReplace(TextoCompleto, '.', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

      SL:= TStringList.Create;
      try
        ExtractStrings([' '], [], PChar(TextoCompleto), SL);
        WriteLn(SL.Text);
        ReadLn;
      finally
        SL.Free;
  end;
      Count:= 0;
      while Count <> SL.Count - 1 do
      begin
          Clipboard.AsText:= SL[Count]; //place text in clipboard
          //if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) then
          //do something with text
          ShowMessage(Clipboard.AsText);
          PostMessage(Appwin.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0);
          PostMessage(FindWindow(PChar(0),'Banrisul').Handle, WM_KEYUP, VK_TAB, 0);
      end; //while Count <> SL.Count - 1 do
      SL.Free;
  end; //if Appwin <> 0 then
end;

end.
```

it's giving an error in:  PostMessage(Appwin.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0);

Why the result in Appwin cannot be used with .Handle?

Comment: And the problem is...?  You did not provide any details about that.  Obviously, your code is not doing what you are expecting it to do, or you would not be asking about it.  But you did not explain what your expectations are to begin with, and what the code is actually doing that you are not expecting.

Comment: It's not finding the window where the paste operation should work on. The Appwin:= FindWindow(PChar(0),'Banrisul'); is not finding the window, but I do have a window with Banrisul in it's name.

Comment: For the record, I haven't voted up, down, or to close any of your questions, but I will say please learn how to use StackOverflow for optimal help. With all due respect, we are not work hogs. And this type of activity is automatically detected by scheduled scripts on StackOverflow's back-end which look for what's called "help zombies". Please look it up if you don't believe me. It's not just a term established here. Repeated attempts to "get help to a bunch of unclear and downvoted questions" can easily lead to a ban if you're not careful.

Comment: Yes I understand. I believe in fact this is not the best place for what I need. What I need is a thread focused in the program that I'm trying to create where I can evolve with the help of others, all in the same thread. stackoverflow works differently, that's why I asked a bunch of questions, but I see it doesn't work. Is there a way to make all my question in this thread and don't open one by one? I will also try to improve the question "quality".

Comment: Whoops, my bad, make that "Help Vampire" similar concept though.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because that's not how StackOverflow works. If you want to post an alternate answer, you need to first edit the question and get it reopened, and then you can post an actual answer to the question itself. Answering your own question is totally acceptable here; the [faq] has more details. Editing to say "Solved. Here's what I used." is inappropriate.

Comment: Fernando: @KenWhite Is *absolutely correct* about reverting your edits. Please stop. Second, your language/attitude are not going to fly here. I trust this is the last time I need to let you know about both of those things, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Appwin` is a window handle. It does not have a `Handle` property. Simply remove the `.Handle`.

```
PostMessage(Appwin, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0);
```

I don't expect this will solve all the problems in that code, but it's the solution to the compiler error that is the subject of this question.

Comment: very good. thanks. it's not finding the "Banrisul" window tho.

Comment: I answered the question that you asked

Comment: Yes. I just don't want to open a new thread to ask about this problem of not finding the window.

Comment: Did you match the name exactly? Also use `nil` rather than `PChar(0)`. Means the same, but `nil` is idiom.

Comment: Just before you sent your comment I realized that it might be looking for the exact name. As you said. Is there a way to slightly modify it to find the "word" in the window name and not the exact title?

Comment: I don't think so. You'd have to roll your own with `EnumWindows`.

Comment: ok, and what about: StringReplace(TextoCompleto, '.', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]); it's not working, no "." is removed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29515/discussion-between-fernandosbs-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: Don't learn a new language in public on stack overflow. Read the documentation. If you would read the documentation for StringReplace you would solve the problem yourself. Try harder to work it out for yourself.